# Filter a spreadsheet with a list of ID's

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-match

I have a large spreadsheet with a ton of information (10,000+ records).  One of the columns is an ID column.

I also have a list of around 500 ID's that need to be excluded from this dataset.

Basically I want filter through the BIG spreadsheet and spit out a spreadsheet with everything excluding the list of ID's that must be excluded.

Example Data:

```
id name email
34 bob  bob@aol.com
59 amy  amy@aol.com
53 rog  rog@aol.com
98 jon  jon@aol.com
```

Filter Data (list of id's I want to filter out):

```
id
34
53
```

The result would look like:

```
id name email
59 amy  amy@aol.com    
98 jon  jon@aol.com
```

What would be the best way to handle this using Excel, Libre Office, or Google Docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sice you don't mention where your 500 list is, assign it a named range (eg `Dlist`, of workbook scope in the same workbook) and apply a formula such as:

```
 =MATCH(A2,Dlist,0)
```

copied down then filter to select for everything other than `#N/A`. and copy what/where required.

Comment: I actually inverted my question on accident, I need to actually filter OUT by ID. Question is revised.

Answer (score 0):

First off, 10,000 records aren't that large, even for wimpy excel.  It would also be helpful to understand a number of factors that are going on here.  What in common do the the 500 records have?  Are they sequential?  Do they share a value in a different field? Have you looked into adding data filters to the headers on your spreadsheet?

It's a pretty straightforward concept but here's a video that steps through how to apply filter's to your columns.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z-IZKtGvUK8#aid=P9_7OGqqdBA

Once the filter is applied, you can subset that column based on a number of criteria. If this doesn't solve your problem, please elaborate.

Also, I see that you've been around on Stack Overflow for a while but you might want to revisit this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  If I had to rank the structure of this question, I would give it a 3/10.

Comment: Thanks Austin, I honestly have never seen the page you referenced, so I will review it for future questions!

Comment: No problem! They're just good practices. Let me know how the excel endeavors go!

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following answer is able to help you.

Sorting through 10,000 records can be intimidating but there are a number of ways in which you can extract the 500 records from the large spreadsheet. I am going to show you a simple solution.

First create a blank spreadsheet in Excel and then copy and paste the 500 ID's into column A. Label this column "ID" or however you would like. Then label the remaining columns of the spreadsheet the same way in which the large spreadsheet is labeled. Then it is time to use Excel's Vlookup function.

Enter this function, into the first record of each column and drag it down. If the formula is correct, it should automatically populate the 500 records with the subsequent values matching the lookup value (which is the ID).

If you are not familiar with the VLookup function, please let me know and I can help. I will need more information about how your spreadsheets are structured.

Comment: I actually inverted my question on accident, I need to actually filter OUT by ID.  Question is revised.